# A checklist for child proofing an iPad pro

Tags: ipad, safari

I have gifted my 9 year old a iPad. However before I let him use it, I need a checklist of all the steps i need to do to child proof the iPad.

1. Configure safari so that all bad searches are blocked
2. All bad sites don't open
3. Search results don't return explicit content.

does apple provide such a list. I googled and I found snippets of information here and there. But I need a complete list of steps.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind no filter is 100%.

To limit access to adult websites, enable Settings → General → Restrictions → Websites → Limit Adult Content.

To enable SafeSearch on Google to hide adult content from search results, go to https://www.google.com/preferences and ‘Turn On SafeSearch’.

Comment: don't need 100% because they are not professional hackers. So basic checks should be fine.

Comment: @Knows true, but I wasn’t talking about being able to bypass the filter intentionally, I mean unintentionally a website may bypass a filter for whatever reason. It’s impossible to accurately determine adult content 100% of the time, sometimes legitimate content is blocked and vice versa.